# Can I unlock bootloader for Mi phone?

Tags: xiaomi

I've been told that I need to ask permission from Xiaomi to unlock bootloader. Why and is there any other way?
Btw, I'm currently using Redmi 5A.

Comment: This link also answers your questions. >[Here's how you do it.](http://en.miui.com/thread-246705-1-1.html)

Comment: The permission is the easy part; you'll then have to log into the account on the phone and wait (3 days to 2 months depending on the situation).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xiaomi-redmi-5a/how-to/bypass-bootloader-lock-redmi-5ariva-t3772381/amp/) is the all information to unlock bootloader of redmi 5a without asking redmi with unofficial way
Pre required-

1. Pc running on Windows.
2. Download Mi flash and Mi drivers from [here](https://xiaomiflashtool.com/download/xiaomi-flash-tool-20180528%22here%22).
3. Download official twrp recovery for redmi 5a [here](https://twrp.me/xiaomi/xiaomiredmi5a.html).
4. Follow the guidelines given in above XDA thread link.

**Good Luck**

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.